# Convergence test of positive series $\sum u_n$ based on $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{\alpha}{n\log n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove the following convergence test:

If $u_n > 0$ and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{\alpha}{n\log n}$, where $\alpha >1$, then $\sum u_n$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the logs of the ratios, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n\log\left(1-\frac1k-\frac\alpha{k\log(k)}\right)
&\le-\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac1k+\frac\alpha{k\log(k)}\right)\\
&\le-\left(\log(n)+\alpha\log(\log(n))-\log(C)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
u_n\le\frac{Cu_2}{n\log(n)^\alpha}
$$
which converges by the integral test when $\alpha\gt1$.

Comment: Thank you @robjohn. Now does similar logic apply to show that $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{nlogn}$, then $\Sigma u_n$ diverges?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: why not see if you can make it work?